# Android studio 2.3 project doesnot run in emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-gradle-plugin

I have copied all files in my MyAppplication4 project in 
new folder MyAppplication5.

C:\Users\AndroidProjects\MyAppplication5\

Gradle build is successfully.

I am getting below error while running MyAppplication5 in emulator,

error details are given below,

```
Installation failed with message Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Split lib_slice_3_apk was defined multiple times.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?
```

Comment: This PROBABLY happens if there is some issue with the package name. Did u change the package name after copying. N BTW this copying isnt very good idea. Instead try to use the import option.

Answer (score 0):

Thats should work:

1. menu>Build>run>clean Project
2. menu>Build> run >Rebuild Project.

You can try upgrade your files in the sdk manager or desinstalling and intalling the apk again if this don´t work

Answer (score 0):

Please try what the error message suggests:

> It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

Uninstall the existing app from the emulator or device and then re-install your app.

Answer (score 0):

Disable `instant run` from `setting > build,execution,deployment > Instant run`

for details you may get your answer here [check my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45334142/uninstalling-an-existing-version-of-the-apk-if-it-is-present-and-then-re-install/45349844#45349844), as it is a duplicate question so won't be able to type here and since i don't have much reputation as well so couldn't commented on your question